# Opening a website form in an (objective C) iOS app embedded browser, and then closing the browser upon submitting the form

Tags: ios, objective-c, browser, native

Our web app has a certain complicated form that will take too long to build out as part of our native (Objective C) iOS app. I was hoping that we could instead open the form from the native app in an embedded browser (a browser built into our native app), and then upon submitting the form in the embedded browser, close the browser and return to a native app screen. Is this technically possible? If so, how can it be done?

If it isn't, then is the following possible? in the native app, have a button to open the form in a non-embedded browser (e.g., Safari), and then automatically close the browser when the form is submitted and return to the native app.

BTW, a co-worker told me that the former is possible with native Android (Java) apps.

Answer (score 3):

Amin Negm-Awad's suggestion seems like the easiest option, but there's also the WebViewJavascriptBridge, to send messages back and forth from Objective-C and Javascript in a UIWebView, it might be worth checking out https://github.com/marcuswestin/WebViewJavascriptBridge

Haven't used it in a while, though.

(this feels like it'd be better as comment but I can't comment yet)

Answer (score 2):

You can have a web view in your app displaying the form. Define an URL scheme for your app and send the form to the app:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1

But you should really recheck, whether you want to use a web form inside your app.

Comment: Thanks. Why should I recheck that?

Comment: 1. You mix two technologies. 2. It is not native.